# I have three lists. I need to print them out together in three columns

Tags: python-3.x, multiple-columns

Below is how I want them printed out

```
           list 1               list 2                 list 3

            1                     1                        1
            2                     2                        2
            3                     3                        3
            4                     4                        4
```

Comment: You can use `zip(list1, list2, list3)` to turn the lists into columns. Other than that... post some code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip`. Suppose you have three lists,

```
>>> a=[1, 2, 7]
>>> b=[3, 4, 8]
>>> c=[5, 6, 9]
```

Then,

```
for row in zip(a, b, c) :
    print (*row)
```

Output :

```
1 3 5
2 4 6
7 8 9
```

Comment: That doesn't work with python 3.x. But `for row in zip(a,b,c):print(*row)` does.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @tdelaney

Answer (score 0):

If all lists have the same length you can iterate through them and get elements by index:

```
l=[1,2,3,4]
l2=[5,6,7,8]
l3=[9,10,11,12]
for i in range(len(l)):
    if i == 0:
        print('l1    l2    l3')
    print('{0}    {1}    {2}'.format(l[i], l2[i], l3[i]))
```

Output:

```
l1    l2    l3
1    5    9
2    6    10
3    7    11
4    8    12
```

Note that if you want straight columns you should to specify length in formatting:

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    if i == 0:
        print('l1    l2    l3')
    print('{0:>{length}}    {1:>{length}}    {2:>{length}}'.format(l[i], l2[i], l3[i], length=2))
```

Output:

```
l1    l2    l3
 1     5     9
 2     6    10
 3     7    11
 4     8    12
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was searching for

```
for row in zip(list1, list2, list3) :
            print ("{0:<10} {1:>8} {2:>16}".format(*row))
```